# Using Channel reference into Timer

Tags: java, timer, netty

I have some troubles trying to use a Channel instance (getting from the 'channelConnected' method) into a Timer ( org.jboss.netty.util.Timer ). Because for use a external variable into a 'TimerTask' is necessary that it's declared 'final'.

What i try to do is when a client is connect, start a Timer and while  the connection is alive send some information through the channel, because i need to use regulars intervals of time. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

```
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        ...
        this.timerLocal.newTimeout(new TimerTask() {
            public void run(Timeout timeout) throws Exception {
                Channel ch = ctx.getChannel();
                ch.write("data data data");
            }
        }, 25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand what exactly your problem is but I think what you are looking for can be done also via the IdleStateHandler and the IdleStateAwareUpstreamHandler.

Just insert an IdleStateHandler which will trigger an idle event on write idle events every x seconds and then create an custom IdleStateAwareUpstreamHandler which will listen to these events and fire Channel.write(...)