# How to handle PING/PONG frame in Netty 4?

Tags: netty

```
class ClientWebSocketHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<WebSocketFrame> {

  @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WebSocketFrame frame) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

I can only receive `TextWebSocketFrame` & `BinaryWebSocketFrame` in `channelRead0`

How to handle `PingWebSocketFrame` and `PongWebSocketFrame`, I want to know when the client sends Ping/Pong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netty has received PingWebSocketFrame and PongWebSocketFrame before any WebSocketFrame arrives at your SimpleChannelInboundHandler.See abstract [WebSocketProtocolHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocketProtocolHandler.java) for its processing logic.

Answer (score 2):

like that:
(knowing that at time channelRead0 is deprecated and should be removed or not supported after 5.0 verserion, ask in comment if you want an up to date answer)

```
/**
 * * <strong>Please keep in mind that this method will be renamed to
 * {@code messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, I)} in 5.0.</strong>
 */
@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    Channel ch = ctx.channel();
    if (!handshaker.isHandshakeComplete()) {
        handshaker.finishHandshake(ch, (FullHttpResponse) msg);
        l.error("WebSocket Client connected!");
        handshakeFuture.setSuccess();
        return;
    }

    if (msg instanceof FullHttpResponse) {
        FullHttpResponse response = (FullHttpResponse) msg;
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected FullHttpResponse (getStatus=" + response.status() + ", content="
            + response.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8) + ')');
    }


    WebSocketFrame frame = (WebSocketFrame) msg;
    if (frame instanceof TextWebSocketFrame) {
        TextWebSocketFrame textFrame = (TextWebSocketFrame) frame;
        l.info("WebSocket Client received message:{} ", textFrame.text());

        //needed if the server close the socket if no ping send for long
        //better to send the ping with a timer
        // it allwos to choose the rate
        ch.write(new PingWebSocketFrame());

    } else if (frame instanceof PongWebSocketFrame) {
        l.info("WebSocket Client received pong");
    } else if (frame instanceof CloseWebSocketFrame) {
        l.info("WebSocket Client received closing");
        ch.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to send ping with a timer?

Comment: try to enclose your channel.write in a timer like that: ``` public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        ...
        this.timerLocal.newTimeout(new TimerTask() {
            public void run(Timeout timeout) throws Exception {
                Channel ch = ctx.getChannel();
                ch.write("data data data");
            }
        }, 25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ...
} ``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934449/using-channel-reference-into-timer